# div inside parent div overlap the text

Tags: html, css, overlapping

This is my code

```css
.pa {
  width: 400px;
  background: #008000;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pa">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    Text Text
    <div class="icon-wrap">
      <a><i class="fa fa-camera pull-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[***Fiddle Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/124320/)

As you can see, the yellow `div` is overlap the text of parent `div`.
I just want to wrap the text to prevent this overlapping .
How can I fix that ?

**Update Note:**
Adding `padding-right:30px` works , but ...
Is there any way to fix changing only `.icon-wrap` class ?

Comment: according to your answers and your comment, the only way remaining would be giving `right: -30px;` to `.icon-wrap` but it will make it outside the parent div. So do you prefer that way.?

Answer (score 1):

Try to give padding-right as per your requirement, the overlapping issue will be resolved.

```
.pa
{
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

Comment: my bad , is there any way that the class `.pa` doesn't need to change ?
just `icon-wrap` .

Comment: else you can resize your container width, and add .icon-wrap{ right:-30px;}

Comment: Nice trick , thanks . But it would be better if it doesn't need to change container width.

Comment: @zey add `box-sizing: border-box` if you do not want the padding to change the width

Answer (score 0):

You have a `absolute` div with `width:30px`. So you set `padding-right:30px` to the `div` which containes the text. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: my bad , is there any way that the class `.pa` doesn't need to change ?
just `icon-wrap` .

Comment: Since you have a absolute div, it behaves like it. You can achieve it using float. But there also you need do write few lines in `.pa` . Whats the problem in editing the `.pa`. Is there any serious issue?

Comment: First , thanks ...And the problem is `.pa` is from difference css and I don't have permission to edit due to the project structure .

Comment: Damn ;-) . So you can set `right:-30px` to `.icon-wrap`. But it cause problem if your HTML DOM is not arranged properly. Try it. If it doesn't work let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use     `padding-right: 30px;` and     `width: calc(400px - 30px);`

Let me know if you have a any query.

```css
.pa {
    width: calc(400px - 30px);
    background: #008000;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="pa">
 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 


<div class="icon-wrap">
<a><i class="fa fa-camera pull-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad , is there any way that the class `.pa` doesn't need to change ?
just `icon-wrap` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and remove the need for absolute positioning:

```css
.pa {
  width: 400px;
  background: #008000;
  display: flex;
}

.icon-wrap {
  min-width: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pa">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    Text Text
    <div class="icon-wrap">
      <a><i class="fa fa-camera pull-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7k2wqmny/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing only `.icon-wrap` class?
 
then, make `.icon-wrap` class styles `right: -40px;`

Answer (score 0):

Since `.pa`'s `position` is `absolute` the only way to avoid overlapping is to give the inner content padding right 30px or by changing its width:

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcny6mu5/)

```css
.pa
{
  width:400px;
  background:#008000;
  position:relative;
}
.p{width: calc(100% - 30px);}
.icon-wrap
{
  height:100%;
  float:right;
  width:30px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
 <div class="pa">
 <div class="p">
 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>


<div class="icon-wrap">
<a><i class="fa fa-camera pull-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pa {
  width: 400px;
  background: #008000;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  float:right;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
 left:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pa">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
    Text Text
    <div class="icon-wrap">
      <a><i class="fa fa-camera pull-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```